# Why is background-color ignored in certain case?

Tags: html, css

I have:

```
<div style="position: relative; width: 500px; background-color:Yellow;">
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">A</div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px;">B</div>
</div>
```

And the `background-color` is ignored. But when I remove the `style` of the first inside-div - the color *is* shown. Why?

Comment: Because both inner divs are positioned absolutely, the outer div has no height.

Comment: why is this tagged asp.net?

Comment: @Graham But they are _inside_ it!

Comment: @sjmarshy Because it's inside an asp.net solution and I thought it might affect it.

Comment: @ispiro When an element is positioned absolutely, it is taken out of the document flow meaning the containing element acts as if it is not there.

Comment: elements with position absoulte don't expand parent div

Comment: @ispiro the asp.net won't affect how the browser interprets your html.

Comment: @Graham Thanks. You can transform your comments to an answer. You were the first to point that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an element is positioned absolutely, it is taken out of the document flow meaning the containing element acts as if it is not there. Because both inner divs are positioned absolutely, the outer div has no height.

Answer (score 3):

Put a height to your first div

Like:

```
<div style="height:30px;position: relative; width: 500px; background-color:Yellow;">
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">A</div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px;">B</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pcAjF/

Comment: But the two inside-divs are inside the outside-div. Doesn't that mean it includes their size?

Comment: Only when you leave one 'inside' division with the absolute position. and give it a height.

Answer (score 2):

`absolute` positioned elements aren't part of the parent dimension. This means that if you have an element that have an `auto` height and it has only a absolute positioned div inside it will result as 0 height, so it won't have any `background-color` if you have specified any.

If you want to make your color appear specify an height or don't make your inner div absolute.

Answer (score 1):

You have an `absolute` `position` for the two inner `<div>`'s so `height` and `width` are zero.

Comment: But they are inside the outside-div. Doesn't that mean it includes their size?